# Программирование POS-клавиатуры

Tags: linux, клавиатура

Есть программируемая POS-клавиатура IMB. Так же присутствует ПО от производителя написанное на Java с помощью которого значения при нажатии клавиш можно менять. Я хотел бы попробовать сделать свою реализацию для Linux, однако никаких зацепок в интернете для такой задачи я не нашел. Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с такой задачей, или знает куда нужно копать, с чего начать.

Comment: как определяется? что-то интересное в  dmesg?